# Chromium's depot tools won't work

Tags: ubuntu, chromium-os

I am really new to linux but I need Chromium's depot tools to download WebRTC's source code.

Anyway, I have been trying to download it by following the instructions on [their website](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools).

However, it always gives me an error on the command "gclient sync" and even "fetch"

I have Python and git installed so those cannot be the reason.

I have read that I must build this shell script --->`build/install-build-deps.sh`

so I tried, and it gave me an error halfway through.

I am really losing my mind over this, I have been trying for a week and then found [another link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md).

And here comes the other question, do I have to get the entire code of the Chromium project? There has got to be a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/354530/edit) by adding the exact error message .

Comment: @GAD3R Thank you, I have already found a solution